# OpenGL models show grid-like lines

Tags: objective-c, opengl

**Shading problem solved; grid lines persist. See Update 5**

I'm working on an .obj file loader for OpenGL using Objective-C.

I'm trying to get objects to load and render them with shading. I'm not using any textures, materials, etc. to modify the model besides a single light source. When I render any model, the shading is not distributed properly (as seen in the pictures below). I believe this has something to do with the normals, but I'm not sure.

These are my results:

[image: Sphere]
[image: Blender Monkey]

And this is the type of effect I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Goal]

I thought the problem was that the normals I parsed from the file were incorrect, but after calculating them myself and getting the same results, I found that this wasn't true. I also thought not having `GL_SMOOTH` enabled was the issue, but I was wrong there too.

So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, so sorry if the question seems vague. If any more info is needed, I'll add it.

Update: 
Link to larger picture of broken monkey head: http://oi52.tinypic.com/2re5y69.jpg

Update 2: If there's is a mistake in the process of me calculating normals, this is what I'm doing:

- Create a triangle for each group of indices.
- Calculate the normals for the triangle and store it in a vector.
- Ensure the vector is normalized with the following function

:

```
static inline void normalizeVector(Vector3f *vector) {
    GLfloat vecMag = VectorMagnitude(*vector);
    if (vecMag == 0.0) {
        vector->x /= 1.0; 
        vector->y /= 0.0;
        vector->z /= 0.0;
    }
    vector->x /= vecMag;
    vector->y /= vecMag;
    vector->z /= vecMag;
}
```

Update 3: Here's the code I'm using to create the normals:

```
- (void)calculateNormals {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfIndices; i += 3) {      
        Triangle triangle;
        triangle.v1.x = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i]*3];
        triangle.v1.y = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i]*3+1];
        triangle.v1.z = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i]*3+2];

        triangle.v2.x = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i+1]*3];
        triangle.v2.y = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i+1]*3+1];
        triangle.v2.z = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i+1]*3+2];

        triangle.v3.x = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i+2]*3];
        triangle.v3.y = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i+2]*3+1];
        triangle.v3.z = modelData.vertices[modelData.indices[i+2]*3+2];

        Vector3f normals = calculateNormal(triangle);
        normalizeVector(&normals);

        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i]*3] = normals.x;
        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i]*3+1] = normals.y;
        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i]*3+2] = normals.z; 

        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i+1]*3] = normals.x;
        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i+1]*3+1] = normals.y;
        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i+1]*3+2] = normals.z; 

        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i+2]*3] = normals.x;
        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i+2]*3+1] = normals.y;
        modelData.normals[modelData.surfaceNormals[i+2]*3+2] = normals.z; 
    }
```

Update 4: Looking further into this, it seems like the .obj file's normals are surface normals, while I need the vertex normals. (Maybe)

If the vertex normals are what I need, if anybody can explain the theory behind calculating them, that'd be great. I tried looking it up but I only found examples, not a theory. (e.g. "get the cross product of each face and normalize it"). If I know what I have to do, I can look it up an individual process if I get stuck and won't have to keep updating this.

Update 5: I re-wrote my whole loader, and got it to work, somehow. Although it shades properly, I still have those grid-like lines that you can see on my original results.

Comment: what do you mean by "blocky"? Do you use textures? Color materials? Materials? Shaders? Something related to those grid lines?

Comment: The grid lines were what I meant by blocky. I'm trying to have it look smooth. The only thing I'm using is a light source; nothing else.

Comment: Update: Added another picture of my results and a picture of what I'm trying to achieve for comparison.

Comment: could you post a link to a much larger version of the (broken) head?

Comment: your face culling appears correct, at least - there's no visible leakage of back-side polygons in the image.  odd...

Comment: @Alnitak Just noticed something (and not sure how to explain it right): if I render a cube, one if its faces is lit differently than the other faces. Could this be causing the effect I'm getting?

Comment: probably not - if that face is orientated more towards the light then it would naturally appear brighter.

Comment: What happens if you render the monkey head with the same normal for every vertex (i.e. pointing up), ignoring the .obj normals?

Comment: (It won't let me edit my comment, so deleting that and posting a new one). If I give every vertex a normal of (0, 1, 0), the monkey head is completely grey.

Comment: that's good - shows that it is the normals that are broken.  Have you ensured your normals are all normalised (i.e. length == 1) ?

Comment: No, I haven't. If I'm understanding you right, you're saying that all the vertices of the normal need to add up to one? If not, how would I check for/handle this?

Comment: @Robert: each normal should be of length 1; it saves a costly per-frame length calculation, so OpenGL assumes it has been done (as does every fragment shader I've ever seen). But that's what you're doing in normalizeVector (ummm, other than the /= 1.0, /= 0.0 stuff inside that one conditional, which I think you mean just to be assignments, not divides)

Comment: @Tommy I'm looking at the values normalizeVector producing, and I'm getting numbers like 0.651230 before the normal is divided by the magnitude, and 0.836514 afterwards. So something is definitely wrong here.

Comment: @Robert: no, that sounds like it could be correct. As long as you end up with x*x + y*y + z*z = 1 (or very, very close to, per usual precision concerns). Running out of ideas, you've not made some minor error like assuming OBJ vertex index and normal index match or that the number of normals will always be the same as the number of vertices or something like that?

Comment: I've gotten magnitudes from 0.7 - 2.0. I take the number of normals from the OBJ file and calculate my own based on that number. I updated my code to show what I'm using to insert the normals.

Answer (score 1):

Your `normalizeVector` function is clearly wrong.  Dividing by zero is never a good idea.  Should be working when `vecMag != 0.0` though.  How are you calculating the normals?  Using cross-product?  When happens if you let OpenGL calculate the normals?

Comment: The if block isn't even being called by any of the models I'm loading, so I'll just remove it. And I'm calculating the normals using cross product. Also, how do I let OpenGL calculate the normals?

Comment: @Robert: `glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL)`, but I don't know if you're using evaluators to generate the geometry.  `glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)` will do the normalization for you, at least.

Comment: I'm not using evaluators; enabling GL_NORMALIZE didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the *direction* of your normals that's at fault - if they're the wrong way around then you'll only see the polygons that are supposed to be pointing away from you.

Try calling:

```
 glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

and see whether your output changes.

Given that we're seeing polygon edges I'd also check for:

```
 glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

Comment: Calling those functions didn't change the output.

Comment: Could still be the direction, supposing the polygons flip direction randomly and the existing renderings were with CULL_FACE disabled. What happens if you ensure face culling is enabled and switch the test in glFrontFace? Are you able to see only back faces correctly? Alternatively, I vote: it's not a clean tesselation (which would be fault of the software that exported), and the reference render is ray traced, not forward rendered. EDIT: suggest you load the OBJ in MeshLab (it's free; Google it) to verify, you can enable lighting in that.

Comment: @Tommy calling glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); and gllFrontFace(GL_CW); allow me to see the back faces, but they're still not shading properly. Also: I downloaded MeshLab, and it loads/shades fine in there. Same with Photoshop.